# Concatenar Fechas en url

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy consumiendo un API

```
  private void OrdenesTrabajoAPI()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/work-orders/?createdAtFrom=2020-12-22T18:00:00.0000000Z&createdAtTo=2021-1-23T18:00:00.0000000Z&number=2596");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        // MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
        List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ob;
    }
```

En esta línea de código esta la URL

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/work-orders/?createdAtFrom=2020-12-22T18:00:00.0000000Z&createdAtTo=2021-1-23T18:00:00.0000000Z");
```

Como ven la URL tiene unos parámetros de fechas que es un rango desde hasta

**createdAtFrom=2020-12-22T18:00:00.0000000Z   &  createdAtTo=2021-1-23T18:00:00.0000000Z&**

necesito hacer esto parametrizable, cree un DateTimePiker lo llame DtDesde y cree otro que lo llame DtHasta **utilizo Windows Form**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente concatene estos en la URL

```
var client=newRestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/workorders/createdAtFrom="+DtDesde+"&createdAtTo="+DtHasta+"");
```

Pero el api me devuelve lo siguiente,   El formato de fecha de creación especificado no es correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que tipo de formato son esas fechas o como podría parametrizarlas desde la url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo habitual es utilizar el formato [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Mediante `ToString(formato)` lo puedes ajustar en caso de requerir solo la fecha.

```
string DtDesde = FechaDesde.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
string DtHasta = FechaHasta.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

En caso de requerir también la hora:

```
string DtDesde = FechaDesde.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"); 
string DtHasta = FechaHasta.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss");
```

Donde FechaDesde y FechaHasta son del tipo DateTime (el valor de los DateTimePiker).

En ocasiones piden el formato completo de ISO 8601, dependiendo de la precisión podemos tener:

```
// ISO8601 con 7 decimales
string DtDesde = FechaDesde.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// "2017-06-26T20:45:00.0700000Z"

// ISO8601 con 3 decimales
string DtDesde= FechaDesde.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// "2017-06-26T20:45:00.070Z"
```

Comment: Formato de fecha y hora admitido
Tanto en las solicitudes como en las respuestas, la API de cloudFleet maneja las fechas como un string en el formato ISO 8601 .

{
    ...
    "createdAt": "2019-03-20T22:16:33.9700000Z"
    ...
}
Importante : La API en sus respuestas siempre devolverá las fechas en UTC-0

Comment: Aun me sigue diciendo que El formato de fecha de creación especificado no es correcto

Comment: He editado la pregunta para incluir el formato completo de la ISO 8601. Parece que requieres la de 7 decimales.